# How to take input via cmd & pass to sqlplus procedure?

Tags: cmd, sqlplus

I want to provide input to `procedure` in `sqlplus` via `cmd`.

How can i get it done ? 
What should I write in `cmd` ?

Answer (score 0):

Pls. check out this link for detailed answer
https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:594023455752

You can use &1 to suppress the input prompt and include the input in the "@" line.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.